# count number of rows in table using php

Tags: php, sql, count, rows

I just want to count the number of rows in a table that already created in a database using php. I used mysqli(). I need the number of rows in the table as the output.

Comment: You'll get better answers if you post your code and tell us where exactly you're having problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <?php
  $mysqli = new mysqli("hostname", "dbusername", "dbpassword", "dbname");

   /* check connection */
   if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
     exit();
   }

  if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT count(*) cc FROM tablename")) {

     /* fetch the first row as result */
     $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row['cc']);

   /* close result set */
    $result->close();
 }

 /* close connection */
 $mysqli->close();
?>
```

In fact it's a common question you can find the answer anywhere.

Like, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

You could separate this problem in to two

1. I wanna know how to connect to mysql.
2. I wanna know how to write that sql instruction.

Comment: Well, you and @RajibGhosh copypasted the same code, but unfortunately it's wrong. The result will always be 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
  $mysqli = new mysqli("hostname", "dbusername", "dbpassword", "dbname");

   /* check connection */
   if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
     exit();
   }

  if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT columnName from tablename")) {

    /* determine number of rows result set */
     $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

    printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);

   /* close result set */
    $result->close();
 }

 /* close connection */
 $mysqli->close();
?>
```

## EDIT:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table`");
$row = $result->fetch_row();
echo '#: ', $row[0];
```

Comment: That's better, but still no cigar. There's no need to fetch all rows just to count them. `count(*)` is a better option.

Comment: @georg please check my updated comment.now is it ok :)

Answer (score 0):

Try simple query like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROM mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use `COUNT` in `SQL`, you can just select all rows `(SELECT id FROM table)` and then just use PHP `count()`.

Answer (score 0):

also you simply do this

```
 "SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Rows`, `any column` FROM `tablename` GROUP BY `any column` ORDER BY `any column` "
```

Comment: Please add some explanation about your answer.

Answer (score -1):

[mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) should do the trick if you want to count the rows in php.