# mysql_fetch_array() coming with strange output

Tags: php, ios, mysql, sql

I'm having a total buzz kill here.
I'm trying to get a result from a query with `mysql_fetch_array()` but its bringing the from value. Here's a quick example:

This is the query:

```
$query = SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM rese WHERE usua_cod = '{$user_cod}';
```

This is the query output on the "database tool":

[image]

This is the PHP code:

```
        $sql_check = mysql_query($query) or die( mysql_error());

        if($sql_check)
        {
            $result_check = mysql_fetch_array($sql_check);
            if($result_check[0] > 0)
            {
                //Erro 
                    $Result = array('Resultado'=>"NO",
                                    "msg"=>"Você já possui uma reserva neste horário",
                                    'debug'=>$result_check[0],
                                    'query'=>"$query",
                                    'res1'=>$result_check);

                    $arrayOfChildren[] = $Result;
                    $myJSON = json_encode($arrayOfChildren);
                    echo($myJSON);
            }
            else
            {
              // DOES THE INSERT CODE
            }
        }
```

On the Xcode console I get this:

```
2014-11-26 21:10:00.784 ezmall[1250:423465] dict : (
        {
        Resultado = NO;
        debug = 1;
        msg = "Voc\U00ea j\U00e1 possui uma reserva neste hor\U00e1rio";
        query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM rese WHERE usua_cod = '{$user_cod}'";
        res1 =         {
            0 = 1;
            total = 1;
        };
    }
)
```

So I thinks there's something kind of messed up because the "0" thats on "res1" should be the result for the "total" and not an index. So, any thoughts?

Cheers.

Comment: `var_dump($sql_check);` prints? And do you see that big red box on the [manual](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array), it is there for a reason ;)

Comment: **WARNING**: This is terrifyingly insecure because those parameters are not [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You should **NEVER** be putting `$_POST` data directly into the query: it creates a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used, it's being removed from PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Comment: you  can see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27144741/count-number-of-rows-in-table-using-php/27144851#27144851)

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_array()` creates a result array with both numeric and named result column keys, so each result value will be in there twice. So the 0 you are seeing is the index for 'result column 0'.

You want to use `mysql_fetch_row()` or `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead, depending on whether you want to have numeric column ids or column names as keys